# using derived class in runtime c++

Tags: c++, pointers, casting, polymorphism, runtime

this is checking in runtime if mybase class is a derived class. I need to call a member variable from say myDerived.member1 using myBase like myBase.member1 in runtime. Here myBase is a pointer. How to do that.

```
if(dynamic_cast<myDerived*>(myBase))
```

Comment: ``dynamic_cast<>`` does not return ``bool``. It either throws an exception or returns a ``myDerived *`` pointer.

Comment: `dynamic_cast<myDerived*>(myBase)->member1`?

Comment: @Carlton `dynamic_cast` throws a `bad_cast` exception on failure when used with references (`dynamic_cast<Derived&>(base)`), which is probably what @user2225104 was referencing.

Comment: @JamesAdkison whoops, I wasn't even thinking about non-pointer types.  Comment deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
myDerived* p_derived = nullptr;
p_derived = dynamic_cast<myDerived*>(myBase);
if (p_derived != nullptr)
   //do something with p_derived->member1;
```

This way you're only making a (possibly expensive) call to `dynamic_cast` once.